# RFID allow write operation only if authenticated

Tags: rfid, encryption

According to [this page at rfidjournal.com](https://www.rfidjournal.com/faq/whats-the-difference-between-read-only-and-read-write-rfid-tags):

> Microchips in RFID tags can be read-write, read-only or “write once, read many” (WORM). With read-write chips, you can add information to the tag or write over existing information when the tag is within range of a reader. Read-write tags usually have a serial number that can’t be written over. Additional blocks of data can be used to store additional information about the items the tag is attached to (these can usually be locked to prevent overwriting of data). Read-only microchips have information stored on them during the manufacturing process. The information on such chips can never be changed. WORM tags can have a serial number written to them once, and that information cannot be overwritten later.

I expect I can write RFID data many times with authentication.

For example, I have RFID with password `123` and it contains data `hello world`. Then I want to overwrite data with `world is saying hello`, but don't allow overwrite if user didn't input password `123`, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that feature is available in some RFIDs. Take for example https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT3H2111_2211.pdf

It has a password protection.

Comment: Can I change the password?

Comment: Should be possible. You should go through the document and confirm it as I am not an expert on this topic.